# RuntimeError: This event loop is already running in python sitemaping

Tags: python, web-crawler, runtime-error, python-asyncio, sitemap

**Code of program**

```
import sys
import logging
from pysitemap import crawler
import pandas
df = pandas.read_excel(r'absoltepath')
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    #row name where excel data exist
    Url=row['data']
if __name__ == '__main__':
    if '--iocp' in sys.argv:
        from asyncio import events, windows_events
        sys.argv.remove('--iocp')
        logging.info('using iocp')
        el = windows_events.ProactorEventLoop()
        events.set_event_loop(el)
    #storing name    
    crawler(Url, out_file=f'{index}sitemap.xml')
```

**Error**

> RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call
> last) ~\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_8812\3669626430.py in 
> 11         events.set_event_loop(el)
> 12     #storing name
> ---> 13     crawler(Url, out_file=f'{index}sitemap.xml')
>
> ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pysitemap_*init*_.py in
> crawler(root_url, out_file, out_format, maxtasks, exclude_urls)
> 19     if exclude_urls:
> 20         c.set_exclude_url(urls_list=exclude_urls)
> ---> 21     loop.run_until_complete(c.run())
> 22
> 23     try:
>
> ~\anaconda3\lib\asyncio\base_events.py in run_until_complete(self,
> future)
> 568         future.add_done_callback(_run_until_complete_cb)
> 569         try:
> --> 570             self.run_forever()
> 571         except:
> 572             if new_task and future.done() and not future.cancelled():
>
> ~\anaconda3\lib\asyncio\base_events.py in run_forever(self)
> 523         self._check_closed()
> 524         if self.is_running():
> --> 525             raise RuntimeError('This event loop is already running')
> 526         if events._get_running_loop() is not None:
> 527             raise RuntimeError(
>
> RuntimeError: This event loop is already running

Comment: Do you have a question?  Are you going to tell us whether the if statement is True or False?  Have you tried it both ways, and if so, does it matter?

Answer (score 0):

**I found myself a solution**

```
import sys
import logging
from pysitemap import crawler
import pandas
if __name__ == '__main__':
    if '--iocp' in sys.argv:
        from asyncio import events, windows_events
        sys.argv.remove('--iocp')
        logging.info('using iocp')
        el = windows_events.ProactorEventLoop()
        events.set_event_loop(el)
df = pandas.read_excel(r'absolutepath')
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    #row name where excel data exist
    Url=row['data']
    #storing name    
    crawler(Url, out_file=f'{index}sitemap.xml')
```